# Play mp3 sound files in asterisk

Tags: centos, mp3, asterisk

I have installed asterisk on my centos system but asterisk only supports wav,gsm but not mp3 .how can i play mp3 sound file in asterisk
I have searched a bit and found that to play mp3 we have to install format_mp3.so module and mpg123   I have installed format_mp3.so module but i dint install mpg123

So my question is that can i install mpg123 manullay likke **yum install mpg123** or do in have to install asterisk again? and install mpg123 during asterisk make command as given in [this](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/mp3player.html)
 and to play mp3 do i nee to install any othe module or anything?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can anybody help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install mpg123 but you will NOT need to install Asterisk again.  Try "yum install mpg123".  If that doesn't install mpg123 you can add the DAG repositories to your system.  Visit [this page](http://dag.wiee.rs/rpm/FAQ.php#B) for instructions on doing that.  Once that's added do a "yum update" and "yum install mpg123"